# MySQL "No database selected" (Using API)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm in the middle of making a React API Spring-boot App with a SQL database (named persons). Everything is launching alright and the database is showing on the react app. But! I made this database days ago and when I go back into Terminal to find it using `SELECT * from persons;` it is telling me

> No database selected".

I also put in 'Describe persons;' ...and nothing. Once you make a database and make a API out of it, can you not change the name of the tables and the content? How can I access this again?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server please correct your tags. And you'll need to provide more information than that as there isn't enough to comment on as it is.

Comment: First select the database. If you don't know how  to select database then you can execute query "USE <your_database_name>" before execution of your query.